# Image with runat=server cannot see code-behind property

Tags: asp.net

I've got the following in my .aspx:

```
<input type="image" src="<%=PayPalButtonImage %>" onserverclick="RedirectToPayPal" runat="server" />
```

In the code-behind I've got this property:

```
protected string PayPalButtonImage
{
    get { return PayPalExpressCheckoutButtonUrl;}
}

protected void RedirectToPayPal()
{

}
```

why can't it see this property or the server method RedirectToPayPal?  I get a runtime error of :

'ASP.cart_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'RedirectToPayPal' and no extension method 'RedirectToPayPal' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.cart_aspx' could be found

Comment: What does your RedirectToPayPal method look like?

Comment: updated with the method...it's not defined yet but that doesn't make a diff.

Comment: What version of .NET are you running this on?

Comment: Post class definition and Page directive if you want people to help?

Answer (score 2):

This may not solve your problem, but I don't think your method signature is correct. Try changing your RedirectToPayPal method to

```
protected void RedirectToPayPal(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: I am not using an ImageButton or any asp.net control

Comment: Anyway, made no difference.  I'm not using a server-control.  I'm using a regular Input tag with runat="server"...so not sure what the event type would be but regardless the problem still remains.

Comment: @coffeeaddict, you may be right, but if you're adding a runat=server tag control, I do think you need to pass in those parameters. It probably didn't fix your current issue, but it might be an issue down the road. Sorry I can't be more help. Would you be able to post your directives? (I know you said its not the problem, but it can't hurt for us to see it).

Comment: I know it's not the directives.  Everything else in the page is fine.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void RedirectToPayPal(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Pretty sure you need those missing arguments for asp.net page related events.

Comment: you do but this is NOT my initial problem of the method not being recognized at runtime.

Comment: And both the property AND the method is not recognized

Comment: You didnt have those arguments in your code above, so thats the first thing that came to mind.  You mentioned neither method or property are found at runtime, are they found at designtime?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is your real problem.  Make sure you have built the solution and that the ASPX points to the code behind file you edited.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the codebehind that's important, it's the Inherits property.  Let's see your class definition and your @Page directive.  If these don't match, the method cannot be found.

Comment: The page directive is fine.  This is a page that's been working fine.  Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are getting the runtime error is becuase you haven't defined an event for this. Try the following:

CS:

```
public event EventHandler RedirectEvent; 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.RedirectEvent += new EventHandler(RedirectToPayPal);
}

protected string PayPalButtonImage
{
   get { return "hello"; }
}

protected void RedirectToPayPal(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //DO Whatever here. 
}
```

**ASPX:**
`<input id="Image1" type="image" src="<%=PayPalButtonImage %>" runat="server" onserverclick="RedirectToPayPal" />`

Comment: If he has AutoEventWireup="false" in his directive, yes, the event would need to be defined this way. (same with asp.net 1.1) However by default that property is set to true, so we don't have to wire them up like that anymore.

Comment: Right...I guess I was over thinking it... I beleive you're correct on your post about the signature.

Answer (score 0):

You're being oddly stubborn about posting code, for someone who is asking for help...

Here's a thought.  Use the ASP controls for what they are designed for and quit trying to game the system:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton" runat="server" OnClick="RedirectToPaypal" />
```

Your original control has no ID property, which is required to fire events on the backend.